# Delete elements of vector from other vector

Tags: c++, stl, c++17, c++14

I want to delete all elements of a vector v which are contained by v2;

Is this solution good or should I use something else ?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v = {1,2,3,4,5,1,2};
    std::vector<int> v2 = {1,2,3};
    
    v.erase(std::remove_if(v.begin(), v.end(), [v2](int x)
    {   
        auto it = std::find(v2.begin(), v2.end(), x);
        return it != v2.end();  
    }), v.end());
    
    for (auto i : v)
    {
        std::cout<<i<< " ";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
4 5
```

Comment: Note: the answer from duplicate only works for sorted vectors. If you want to deal with non-sorted vectors, your attempt is probably as good as it can be.

Comment: Reopened because of @Yksisarvinen's argument.

Comment: "_Is this solution good_ [...]" How would you define "good"?

Comment: @KarlD -- You have a 7 element vector and a 3 element vector.  Unless you are actually dealing with thousands or millions of elements, your test case is miniscule, thus anything is "fast" or good enough.

Comment: @KarlD why can't you assign the result of the set difference to the first vector variable? What is the functional difference (especially with data this tiny)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite good for small filtering `v2`. It is a bit better if you pass `v2` by reference.

```
v.erase(std::remove_if(v.begin(), v.end(), [&v2](int x)
{   
    std::find(v2.begin(), v2.end(), x) != v2.end();  
}), v.end());
```

If `v2` is large it is better to replace it with `std::unordered_set<int> s`. It also removed duplicates in `v2`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_set>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v = {1,2,3,4,5,1,2};
    std::vector<int> v2 = {1,2,3};
    std::unordered_set<int> s(v2.begin(), v2.end());
    
    v.erase(std::remove_if(v.begin(), v.end(), [&s](int x) { return s.count(x); }),
            v.end());
    
    for (auto i : v)
    {
        std::cout<<i<< " ";
    }

    return 0;
}
```